# How to Bind ul li tag using jquery in asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, json

i have written this code but not getting  result as i want. please help me

javascript code is

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "userControls/Wsc_comn.asmx/BindCategory",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: true,
  success: OnSuccess,
  error: OnError
});

function OnSuccess(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $("#tablet").append("<li><a rel='external' href='" + this.attachment_url + "'>" + value.Product_name + "</li>");
  });
}

function OnError(data) {

}
```

c# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public string BindCategory()
    { 



      string qry = "select *from products where Product_type='TABLETS'";
      DataTable dt = dllmain.ExecuteselectQry_returns_datatable(qry);
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
        string urls = row["attachment_url"].ToString();
        string catname = row["Product_name"].ToString();



      }
      return dllgetinfo.getdatatabletojson(dt);


   }
```

Comment: Please can you be more specific - "not getting the result as I want" doesn't really tell us much about what is wrong with the above code

Comment: data is not showing in ul li but when running webservice getting all data as it is  in db

Comment: can you insert `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`; just before your "each" loop, and then post (a small sample of) the result into your question so we can see what the returned data looks like. I think the data structure is probably key to this, if you are saying that the ajax call is working.